# What does "like a moose needs a hat rack" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

It's a quote from the movie "[Requiem for a Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem_for_a_Dream)"

> Such a son, a goner. If your mother needs you like a moose needs a hat rack.

What does he mean when he says "like a moose needs a hat rack"?

EDIT: What I wanted to ask is how can you say this with other words or phrases.

Comment: “need that like a hole in the head”

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you go to a dictionary to look up “hatrack.” For example,

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hatrack

Then go to google and look at a picture of a bull moose’s antlers. For example,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moose

Then ponder seriously how many hats even the most sartorial moose owns.

Finally, decide whether a moose is likely to need a hatrack.

Comment: Every so often one comes across an answer that is not only correct, useful and to the point, but also deeply satisfying.

Comment: It's a good thorough answer, and shows how to research something, but it's a little on the sarky side.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I must plead guilty to some sarcasm. I hate voting to close a newbie’s question, and I am not sure that comments asking for what the poster did before asking the question are efficient or even helpful. I prefer to show the poster how to answer his or her own question in the future and encourage them to do so with some mild sarcasm